# How to select all files in a given directory recursively in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, glob

I have a bash script that does some transformations to .svg files.
My script looks something like this:

```
FILES=./src/svg/*.svg

for f in $FILES
do
  ...do stuff
  echo $f
done
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
-script.sh
|
- svg/
  |--logo1.svg
  |--logo2.svg
  |-- subdir/
      |--nested1.svg
      |--nested2.svg
```

I need to be able to process all the `.svg` files under the `svg/` directory and all subdirectories recursively.  Unsurprisingly, `FILES=./src/svg/*.svg` gets all the svgs directly under `svg/` as expected.  Everything else I've tried has come up short:

`FILES=./src/svg/**/*.svg` gets all the svgs in `subdir/` but none directly under `svg` - I expected the recursion to be inclusive.

`FILES=./src/svg/**/*.svg` does the same.

`FILES=./src/svg/*/**/*.svg` says no such file or directory

`FILES=./src/svg/{,**/}*.svg` works at the command prompt but not in my script!  And I do need it in a script :\

So how do make it so that FILES represents all the `svg` files in the `svg/` directory and subdirectories?

Comment: use the `find ... -print0` command and iterate over its output with `read -r -d'' svgfile; do stuf; done < <(find...)`, or `find ./svg -type -f -iname '*.svg' -exec bash -c 'for $svgfile; do stuff with "$svgfile"; done' _ {} +`

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020